# How to send correctly FormData with XMLHttpRequest and simple JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the form:

```
<form id="login_form">
    Login<br/>
    user: <input id="login_user" name="login_user" type="text" /><br/>
    pass: <input id="login_pass" name="login_pass" type="password" /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="doStuff(&quot;login&quot;)" />
</form>
```

this is the js I used:

```
function doStuff(doWhat){

    var sendString = new FormData(document.getElementById("login_form"));

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "?action="+doWhat, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            //do stuff
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(sendString);
}
```

The PHP page only has `echo var_dump($_POST);`

If I send it like that it returns this, that I have no idea how to use:

```
D:\wamp64\www\test\index.php:18:
array (size=1)
  '------WebKitFormBoundaryubX9lqZJrSEuJwB9
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name' => string '"login_user"

admin
------WebKitFormBoundaryubX9lqZJrSEuJwB9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login_pass"

swordfish
------WebKitFormBoundaryubX9lqZJrSEuJwB9--
' (length=173)
```

If I try anything else, like using `JSON.stringify()` on the FormData before sending it or changing the content type from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `multipart/form-data` it just returns an empty array. I should not use jQuery for this. Is there a way to send something usable or make the PHP page able to read it?

Comment: In case of successful Ajax request , you could retrieve the response from your php page by : `xmlhttp.responseText` . In your case it should be instead of `//do stuff` . Try `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` and let me know .

Comment: @Ashraf I'm looking at the response via the network tab in Chrome's DevTools. Just in case I placed a div on the page and added `document.getElementById("test_div").innerHTML = this.responseText;` in place of `//do stuff` and it shows the same thing. I can't extract any variables out of that response in the PHP page.

Comment: php script please

Comment: @KunalAwasthi The PHP page only has `echo var_dump($_POST);`, I said as much in the question.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @KunalAwasthi Take the values from this form (the form can be very big) and send them via AJAX to a PHP page. Preferably the above example should have made this condition true: `$_POST["login_user"] == "admin" && $_POST["login_pass"] == "swordfish"`